# 413 'Request Entity Too Large' using Python and postcodes.io API

Tags: python, api, docker, http-post, http-status-code-413

I have a huge array of postcodes and I want to use "postCodes.io" API which gives the longtitude and altitude data for given postCode in python.

When I request only for 3-4 postCodes It doesnt give an error but when I want for a huge amount of data it gives the "413 error". How should I use python to wait needed amount of time and try again to use the API ?

Or is it possible to change this request limit If I download the API in my local machine and run with docker ?
https://postcodes.io/docs#Install-notes

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

file = 'DataSets/deneme.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)

postCodeArray = []

for postCode in df['PostCode']:
    postCodeArray.append(postCode)

parameters = {
    "postcodes": json.dumps(postCodeArray)   #should be used.["OX49 5NU", "M32 0JG", "NE30 1DP"]
}

response = requests.post("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes", data=parameters)
data = response.json()
```

file = deneme.csv looks like this:

```
Transaction Unique Identifier,PostCode,Town/City
{8A78B2B0-5D07-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},SG5 1RT,HITCHIN
{8A78B2B0-5D09-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},AL3 4GD,ST ALBANS
{8A78B2B0-5D0A-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},WD25 0NF,WATFORD
{8A78B2B0-5D0C-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},WD7 7NN,RADLETT
{8A78B2B0-5D0D-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},SG6 4LU,LETCHWORTH GARDEN CITY
{8A78B2B0-5D0E-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},SG9 9JH,BUNTINGFORD
{8A78B2B0-5D11-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},WD7 7JA,RADLETT
{8A78B2B0-5D12-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},SG12 9DZ,WARE
{8A78B2B0-5D17-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},SG6 3BA,LETCHWORTH GARDEN CITY
{8A78B2B0-5D18-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},SG6 3BA,LETCHWORTH GARDEN CITY
{8A78B2B0-5D1B-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},WD17 4UH,WATFORD
{8A78B2B0-5D1C-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},HP2 7QF,HEMEL HEMPSTEAD
{8A78B2B0-5D2E-5CB0-E053-6B04A8C0F504},HP2 4BA,HEMEL HEMPSTEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey everyone working with the API gave me result. As @john doe said I tried to find the maximum amount of postCodes that I can request at a time. **It was 100 per request**. However having 4 gb data didnt make it easy to take calculate all of them. So I found PostCode Zip file for UK and the problem solved.

**Also I found out how to limit your request:** By using another api called [ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are sending one massive request from the entire list. Instead, you could send multiple smaller requests with a few post codes per request, and append the output of each request to a list.

The HTTP error 413 "Request Entity Too Large" is not caused by rate limiting, but by the size of a singular request. You can try sending a massive GET or POST request to many servers and get the same error message.

Try only querying 3-4 postcodes at a time (Or find the maximum limit and request that number each time).

Comment: Is there any possible automation for querying small amount of postcodes and requesting post like that ?